# Call a function without using eval?

Tags: javascript

I have an object attached as `data` to a DIV. I also have a string that contains the name of a function of that object.

```
function callFunction(divId, funcName, data) {
  o = $(divId).data('myObject');
  // how do I call o.funcName(data) ???

// Somewhere else...
callFunction('#myDivId', "myFunction", someData);
```

The `divId` and `funcName` are actually coming from a Java applet on the page, which is why they're strings.

Comment: You have to use eval() to turn the string into an object, otherwise it's just a string. But beware the security issues around the use of eval()

Comment: I think you want `o[funcName](data)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it is a global function:

```
window['foo']()
```

is the same as to

```
foo()
```

Comment: It's not a global function. It's on an object hanging off a DIV. See `o = $(divId).data('myObject')` above.

Comment: In that case: `the_div['foo']()`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your functions scope. It it's attached to the window, you can do this;

```
<script>
    var my_dynamic_function = function(param) {
        alert(param);
    };

    var callFunction = function(divId, funcName, data) {
        ...
        window[funcName]('PARAM!');
    };

    ...

    callFunction('#myDivId', 'my_dynamic_function', data);
</script>
```